# How to subract row wise mean from each value of column and get one row wise max after subracting mean value pyspark

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark

I want to calculate row wise mean and subract mean from each value of row and get maximum at he end

```
here is my dataframe 


 col1 | col2 | col3
  0   |  2   |  3
  4   |  2   |  3
  1   |  0   |  3
  0   |  0   |  0

df=df.withColumn("mean_value",(sum(col(x) for x in df.columns[0:2]) / 3).alias("mean"))
```

i can calculate row wise mean with line of code , but i want to minus mean value from each value of row and get the maximum value of row after subtraction of mean value.

```
Requeire results

 col1 | col2 | col3   mean_Value    Max_difference_Value
  0   |  2   |  3        1.66             1.34
  4   |  2   |  3        3.0              1.0
  1   |  0   |  3        1.33             1.67
  1   |  0   |  1        0.66             0.66

Note this is main formula: abs(mean-columns value).max()
```

Comment: see `greatest` function.

Comment: @samkart i don't know how to subract mean value from each column value in row

Answer (score 0):

Using `greatest` and list comprehension.

```
spark.sparkContext.parallelize(data_ls).toDF(['col1', 'col2', 'col3']). \
    withColumn('mean_value', (sum(func.col(x) for x in ['col1', 'col2', 'col3']) / 3)). \
    withColumn('max_diff_val', 
               func.greatest(*[func.abs(func.col(x) - func.col('mean_value')) for x in ['col1', 'col2', 'col3']])
               ). \
    show()

# +----+----+----+------------------+------------------+
# |col1|col2|col3|        mean_value|      max_diff_val|
# +----+----+----+------------------+------------------+
# |   0|   2|   3|1.6666666666666667|1.6666666666666667|
# |   4|   2|   3|               3.0|               1.0|
# |   1|   0|   3|1.3333333333333333|1.6666666666666667|
# |   0|   0|   0|               0.0|               0.0|
# +----+----+----+------------------+------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [UDFs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.3/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.udf.html)?

```
from pyspark.sql.types import FloatType
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
import numpy as np

@udf
def udf_mean(col1, col2, col3):
    return np.mean([col1, col2, col3])

df = df.withColumn("mean_value", udf_mean(col1, col2, col3))
```

Similarly you can try for max difference value.

Comment: note - UDFs are slow and shouldn't be used unless required by the complexity. one should always try using pyspark sql functions first.